# Cannot expose the header file to the public in a custom cocoa touch framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am using Objective C. I have a custom cocoa touch framework and a client project which embeds that framework.
In the cocoa touch framework, I use a framework called **Mantle.h**, **which is installed with CocoaPod**s.

I try to make a header file called **AgentLoginRequestModel.h** to be public header in the cocoa touch framework

**AgentLoginRequestModel.h**:

```
    #import "MTLModel.h"
    #import "Mantle.h"

    @interface AgentLoginRequestModel : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>

    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *companyId;
    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *langId;
    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *userId;
    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *password;

    @end
```

Next, I embed the .framework generated from my cocoa touch framework to the client project, import the header using **#import "ParentFramework/AgentLoginRequestModel.h"** and run the code in simulator. Error **"MTLModel.h file not found"** occur in line #import "MTLModel.h" **in AgentLoginRequestModel.h inside the .framework#import "MTLModel.h"**

I has already tried to put Mantle.framework or libMantle.a into Build Phases > Copy Files with the Framework destination, but it still cannot expose the MTLModel.h to the public.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: use this `#import <MTLModel.h>`

Comment: try #import<ParentFolder/MTLModel.h>

Comment: Thanks for your replies
I try to change "Mantle.h" to <Mantle/MTLModel.h>  in AgentLoginRequestModel.h, but it does not help unfortunately.

I also try to change "ParentFramework/AgentLoginRequestModel.h" to <ParentFramework/AgentLoginRequestModel.h>, but it does not work also. Sad